# What is the difference between cold and hot reboot in openstack

Tags: openstack

I am new to openstack for virtualization.
I can reboot instance by 2 ways: cold and hard reboot.
I can understand the difference on a physical computer, but what is the difference between cold and hot reboot on a VM ?

Thanks

Comment: Quoting the OS documentation found here: [OS documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/cli-reboot-an-instance.html)
"You can soft or hard reboot a running instance. A soft reboot attempts a graceful shut down and restart of the instance. A hard reboot power cycles the instance." My guess is, the soft reboot is equivalent to issuing the command "reboot", meanwhile the hard reboot is equivalent to unplugging the instance

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the documentation here that it's already mentioned on this thread:

http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/cli-reboot-an-instance.html

A hard-reboot also affects the virtual machine at hypervisor level. Example: If you are using libvirt-based hypervisors (qemu/kvm), the instance control file (the libvirt XML representing the virtual machine in Libvirt) get's reconstructed from scratch.

That's very usefull when for any reason the instance storage space (/var/lib/nova/instances/INSTANCE_UUID) suffers any kind of problem, or, in general for any reason that you need OpenStack to reconstruct the libvirt definitions !.

It affects both the XML libvirt definition normally stored at /etc/libvirt/qemu and the copy at /var/nova/instances/INSTANCE_UUID.

So, in resume: Use hard-reboot if you need to fully reset/reboot the instance up to Hypervisor level. As you can see, is more like a "power-cycle with steroids".

Hope this helps !!